# mtouch failed with the following message: Unhandled exceptions

Tags: ios, sdk, xamarin.ios

I have upgraded from iOS SDK 4.2 to iOS SDK 5.0. When I now try to compile my current project I get the error below.

Any ideas on what is going wrong here ? I have read all 'mtouch failed with...' that I could find, but none of them seemed to be this exact one.

Any help highly appreciated.

boris

-- start error message --

> Error 1: mtouch failed with the following message:
>
> Unhandled Exception: Exception(s) occurred : . [ Exception(s) occurred
>   : . [ System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   ApplicationName='/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2',
>   CommandLine='-gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -arch armv6 
>   -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
>   -c /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.6.s
>   -o /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.6.o
>   ', CurrentDirectory=''   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0    at MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String
>   args, System.String[] env) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at MTouch.Compile (System.String ifile,
>   System.String ofile, System.String kind, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at MTouch.Assemble (System.String afile,
>   System.String ofile, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in :0
>   at MTouch+c_*AnonStorey4.<>m*_5 (System.String afile)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+c_*AnonStorey4E`1[System.String].<>m__4E
>   (System.String e, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState s,
>   System.Object l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey4D`2[System.String,System.Object].<>m*_4C
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory+c_*AnonStorey15.<>m*_A
>   (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000]
>   in :0  ]  ]
>
> [ Exception(s) occurred : . [ System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   ApplicationName='/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2',
>   CommandLine='-gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -arch armv6 
>   -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
>   -c /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/monotouch.dll.6.s
>   -o /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/monotouch.dll.6.o
>   ', CurrentDirectory=''   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0    at MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String
>   args, System.String[] env) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at MTouch.Compile (System.String ifile,
>   System.String ofile, System.String kind, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at MTouch.Assemble (System.String afile,
>   System.String ofile, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in :0
>   at MTouch+c_*AnonStorey4.<>m*_5 (System.String afile)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+c_*AnonStorey4E`1[System.String].<>m__4E
>   (System.String e, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState s,
>   System.Object l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey4D`2[System.String,System.Object].<>m*_4C
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory+c_*AnonStorey15.<>m*_A
>   (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000]
>   in :0  ]  ]
>
> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: Exception(s) occurred : . [
>   Exception(s) occurred : . [ System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   ApplicationName='/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2',
>   CommandLine='-gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -arch armv6 
>   -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
>   -c /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.6.s
>   -o /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/Mono.Security.dll.6.o
>   ', CurrentDirectory=''   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0    at MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String
>   args, System.String[] env) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at MTouch.Compile (System.String ifile,
>   System.String ofile, System.String kind, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at MTouch.Assemble (System.String afile,
>   System.String ofile, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in :0
>   at MTouch+c_*AnonStorey4.<>m*_5 (System.String afile)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+c_*AnonStorey4E`1[System.String].<>m__4E
>   (System.String e, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState s,
>   System.Object l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey4D`2[System.String,System.Object].<>m*_4C
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory+c_*AnonStorey15.<>m*_A
>   (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000]
>   in :0  ]  ]
>
> [ Exception(s) occurred : . [ System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception:
>   ApplicationName='/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/gcc-4.2',
>   CommandLine='-gdwarf-2 -miphoneos-version-min=4.0 -arch armv6 
>   -std=c99 -I/Developer/MonoTouch/SDKs/MonoTouch.iphoneos.sdk/usr/include -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.0.sdk
>   -c /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/monotouch.dll.6.s
>   -o /var/folders/Te/TerQea8gFpCs2+K1388cP++++TI/-Tmp-/tmp38989c7f.tmp/monotouch.dll.6.o
>   ', CurrentDirectory=''   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_noshell
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start_common
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo,
>   System.Diagnostics.Process process) [0x00000] in :0 
>   at System.Diagnostics.Process.Start
>   (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo startInfo) [0x00000] in :0    at MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String
>   args, System.String[] env) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   MTouch.RunCommand (System.String path, System.String args) [0x00000]
>   in :0    at MTouch.Compile (System.String ifile,
>   System.String ofile, System.String kind, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in
>   :0    at MTouch.Assemble (System.String afile,
>   System.String ofile, Int32 arch) [0x00000] in :0
>   at MTouch+c_*AnonStorey4.<>m*_5 (System.String afile)
>   [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+c_*AnonStorey4E`1[System.String].<>m__4E
>   (System.String e, System.Threading.Tasks.ParallelLoopState s,
>   System.Object l) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel+<ForEach>c__AnonStorey4D`2[System.String,System.Object].<>m*_4C
>   () [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory+c_*AnonStorey15.<>m*_A
>   (System.Object o) [0x00000] in :0    at
>   System.Threading.Tasks.Task.InnerInvoke () [0x00000] in :0    at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThreadStart () [0x00000]
>   in :0  ]  ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because the iOS 5 SDK renamed gcc (from gcc-4.2 to gcc). You can either upgrade to MonoTouch 5 where we've fixed this problem, or make sure gcc-4.2 continue to exist by adding a symlink:

cd /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin
sudo ln -s gcc gcc-4.2

Comment: The latest 4.0.x and 4.2.x versions of MonoTouch were also fixed to use **gcc** when **gcc-4.2** is not available. OTOH the symlink trick will work with any version.

Comment: Thanks ! This indeed fixed the issue.

Comment: Boris, you should mark the question as answered (i.e. the green checkmark under the votes) so other people looking for answers will know a solution is available.

Comment: Poupou, sorry for not doing that. Although very very late, I have done so now. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set Base SDK to the Latest iOS(iOS 5.0) in your project build settings?